# Exchange EWS Managed API Error while Updating EmailMessage on certain properties

Tags: c#, outlook, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I am working against the **Exchange 2010 EWS Managed API** and trying to update emails (`EmailMessage`).

While updating the `EmailMessage's Sender.Name` property, I get an exception upon `Update()`, but if I try to update the `EmailMessage's Subject`, it works just fine.

```
private void UpdateEmail(ItemId itemId)
{
    try
    {
        EmailMessage emailMessage = EmailMessage.Bind(service, itemId, new PropertySet(EmailMessageSchema.Sender, EmailMessageSchema.Subject));

        // Test 1 - this works:
        emailMessage.Subject = "Testing";
        emailMessage.Update(ConflictResolutionMode.AlwaysOverwrite);  

        // Test 2 - this does NOT work (if I comment out the previous 2 lines btw):
        emailMessage.Sender.Name = "John Smith";
        emailMessage.Update(ConflictResolutionMode.AlwaysOverwrite);  // exception thrown
        ...
```

I get the following error from Test 2:

```
The request failed schema validation: The element 'Updates' in namespace 'http:/
/schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types' has incomplete content. Lis
t of possible elements expected: 'AppendToItemField, SetItemField, DeleteItemFie
ld' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types'.
```

Answer (score 1):

EWS doesn't support changing the Sender address via the Strongly typed properties like you are trying. The only way they maybe successful is to modify the underlying extended properties and generating oneoff or wrapped entry-id where applicable the props you need to update are

PR_SENDER_ADDRTYPE_W

PR_SENDER_EMAIL_ADDRESS_W

PR_SENDER_NAME_W

PR_SENDER_ENTRYID

PR_SENDER_SEARCH_KEY

PR_SENT_REPRESENTING_EMAIL_ADDRESS_W

PR_SENT_REPRESENTING_ADDRTYPE_W

PR_SENT_REPRESENTING_NAME_W

PR_SENT_REPRESENTING_ENTRYID

PR_SENT_REPRESENTING_SEARCH_KEY

Note there maybe others as well you need to use a MAPI editor like OutlookSpy of MFCMapi to look at an item yourself.

Cheers
Glen